# Ignore nested property - AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a model and a readmodel:

RequestModel:

```
id: number:
```

RequestReadModel:

```
id: number;
versionInfo: VersionInfoReadModel
```

VersionInfoReadModel:

```
id: number;
latestRequestId: number;
```

RequestReadModel:

```
id: number;
versionInfo: VersionInfoReadModel
```

So when I try to map my model with this code:

```
CreateMap<Request, RequestReadModel>()
```

I get an error that the versionInfo is not mapped, which is a normal error. But the problem is that I need to ignore those properties.
When I try to ignore the readmodel with this code:

```
CreateMap<Request, RequestReadModel>()
.ForMember(x => x.VersionInfo, y => y.MapFrom(model => model));
```

I'm getting this error

> "message": "An error has occurred.",
>     "exceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
>     "exceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",

And when I try to map the properties manually I'm getting an error that you can't map nested models.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Thanks,
Brent

Comment: What are the member variables of Request class, Also what is the version of auto mapper that you are using?

Comment: @PrasanthVJ The member variables on the request class are all the same except on the readmodel is the versionInfo(without the versionInfo it is working properly). The version I am using is 5.0.2.0 –

Comment: Provide complete code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
CreateMap<RequestModel, RequestReadModel>().ForMember(d => d.versionInfo, o => o.Ignore());
```